# exit status 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. when I tried to use nvm use 14.16.1 on a folder?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I tried checking Every questions but not that relevant. I don't know what was the issue when I switch my node to older version using nvm use. It shows the above error as Exit 32

Comment: One needed file is most likely in use. You haven't stated your O.S. (Windows, Linux, ...). A quick solution would be to restart your system to unlock the file and restart the procedure.

Comment: any solution on this? same issue here :(